# MATLAB outputs are not updating after running

Tags: matlab, workspace

I've done a project in MATLAB. Outputs stay the same after each running and they are not refreshing. I change the code but outputs stay the same! I've also used `clear` in the beginning of my `main.m`. Sometimes there will be a change after restarting the system.

This is part of `main.m`.

```
%mainY.m ---- Codec for Single Video Sequence
clear;clc;
addpath('.\Videos');
```

.
.
.

```
%---------------------Parameters Setting---------------------%
yuvfilename = 'foreman_cif_30fps.yuv';
format      = 'cif'; 
frame_rate  = 30;
GOP_len     = 10; % Even !
PrSname = ['GOP',num2str(GOP_len),'_PrS1'];
load([PrSname,'.mat']); % Prediction Structure
GOP_num     = 10;
frame_num   = GOP_len*GOP_num + 1;
init2last   = [0,frame_num-1]; 
blk_sz      = 16;
subrates    = [0.7,0.1];  % Key Parameter of Controlling Bitrate
bitdepths   = [8,8];      % Key Parameter of Controlling Bitrate
total=0;
```

.
.
.

```
  %-----------------------Main Program-------------------------%
...
```

.
.
.
Here is output part:

```
%------------------------Evaluation--------------------------%
psnr = zeros(frame_num,1);
SSIM = zeros(frame_num,1);
for ii = 1:frame_num
    psnr(ii) = Psnr(Y(:,:,ii),Y_rec(:,:,ii));
    SSIM(ii) = ssim(Y(:,:,ii),Y_rec(:,:,ii));
end
mean_psnr = mean(psnr);
mean_SSIM = mean(SSIM);
encode_rate = frame_num/tte;
decode_rate = frame_num/ttd;
encode_time = tte/frame_num;
decode_time = ttd/frame_num;
bitrate = (tbs/frame_num)*frame_rate/1000;
disp('%-----Evaluation Results-----%')
disp(['Qua. Method --> ',Qmethod])
disp(['Rec. Method --> ',Rmethod])
disp(sprintf('Bit-rate      = %-8.2f kbps',bitrate))
disp(sprintf('Mean PSNR     = %-8.2f dB',mean_psnr))
disp(sprintf('Mean SSIM     = %-8.4f ',mean_SSIM))
disp(sprintf('Encoding-rate = %-8.4f frame/s',encode_rate))
disp(sprintf('Decoding-rate = %-8.4f frame/s',decode_rate))
disp(sprintf('Encoding Time = %-8.4f s/frame',encode_time))
disp(sprintf('Decoding Time = %-8.4f s/frame',decode_time))
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can understand and help

Comment: It's not just one file but many files...about 10 maybe

Comment: We are not interested in the whole code. We are interested in the Minimal code that produces the same problem. Read how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: What Sardar is saying is important. What you describe is not possible, so there must be something you are doing wrong. But we can not know if you do not show how you do things.

Comment: As this code is, it should change the output if `%-Main Program-%` changes the variables. So either your code does not use inputs and change then to outputs, or all code results in the same data. There is no way we can help you with this

Comment: Do you have multiple `main.m` files. The comment in the first line indicates this, `%mainY.m`?

Comment: @Jørgen Yes but I've never run the other one.